# Fancy tree: How to call two endpoint according to result

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I am using fancy tree in my application UI:

```
f_tree = $("#nodes_tree").fancytree({
        extensions: ["table"],
        table: {
            indentation: 24,
            nodeColumnIdx: 0
        },
        source: [
            {
                title: "/",
                key: "jcr:root",
                folder: true,
                lazy: true,
            }
        ],
        lazyLoad: function (event, data) {
            let node = data.node;
            let path = buildPath(node);
            if (path !== '/') {
                data.result = {
                    url: 'http://localHost:8080/getDetails'
                };
            } else {
                data.result = elasticResponse;
            }
        },
        postProcess: function (event, data) {
            if (data.response) {
                data.result = data.response._paths;
            }
        },
        renderColumns: function (event, data) {
            let d = data.node.data,
                $tdList = $(data.node.tr).find(">td");
            if (d.attributes) {
                //console.info(`step 333`);
                $tdList.eq(1).text(d.attributes['title'])         
            }
        }
});
```

I am not able to write condition, if "http://localHost:8080/getDetails/1234" will return {} blank json response instead of {"_paths":[{"title":"..."}]"} response then it should call another url i.e; "http://localHost:8087/getAnotherDetails/1234". Please let me know how I can achieve this in fancy tree.

Comment: You could fetch the data from the first yourself, and pass back the url to use based on the result.

Comment: Actually my application renders number of request ids in tree table. When I click on particular request id, then API call happens. I can not fetch data before fancy tree render because API call depend upon request ids present in table.

Comment: I can't see a way to do it in the component configuration. As a workaround - could you do it serverside?

Comment: Actually, you can do what I suggested: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData#use-a-deferred-promise or in the Post-processing hook described afterwards.

Comment: I am checking data.result field and put some condition on it, how can I now again call lazyLoad function depending on data.result in postProcess